# Change Tabs name by using a list and find function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of names in one workbook in column `b` and I have to change the name of tabs of a different workbook in which several tabs.

These tabs have that name in it but not in the same place on every sheet. So, I need to find the name in the workbook by using the list, that I have in a different workbook in `b column`.

Is there any VBA code for that because I am not able to find that particular name in the workbook by using Find in VBA.
Here is the Code which i am trying to use but not able to get the desired result

```
Sub change_Name_1 ()
For i = 1 To Application.Sheets.Count
    Windows("Book2").Activate
    b = Range("B" & i).Value
    Windows("Book1").Activate
    Sheets(i).Select
    Cells.Find(What:=b, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Select
    ActiveSheet.Name = b
    Next
End Sub
```

Image of excel file in which I have the name

[image]

And this is the second image in which name is not in particular cell of every tab

[image]

Comment: So each tab in other workbook has one name from the list in column B of sheet (?) of ThisWorkbook in it and when you find a match you want to name the sheet after that match?

Comment: Reading between the lines (because I'm not clear as to what it is that you are asking for) and if your question is what @QHarr has outlined, it seems a simple `For Each` loop with `.UsedRange` combination should resolve the issue.. but lets see what your response is to QHarr's question

Comment: You've got your `i` variable used as a row counter and a sheet counter at the same time - try using separate variables for each - the basic code is correct but you're not going to find row1 name on sheet1 for definite!

Comment: yes i want to do same thing said by QHarr

Comment: If each entry in column B is in one of the sheets it might be quicker to loop through the sheets and search for each value in the list. Even quicker if it's the only cell with a value in the whole sheet.

Comment: no other cells also have some values in it @SJR

Comment: Are you saying that e.g. sheet2 has a cell containing "arjun" and every other cell is blank?

Comment: i have changed the variable for row counter as well as for column counter but still i am getting the run time error '91'. i am getting the error in find part of the code @jamheadart

Comment: other cells are not blank @SJR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this? You will get an error if trying to activate a range which does not exist so you need to first check that the value is found.

```
Sub change_Name_1()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, r As Range, r1 As Range

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Book1") 'change names to suit
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Book2")

For Each r In wb2.Sheets(1).Range("B1", wb2.Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For Each ws In wb1.Worksheets
        Set r1 = ws.UsedRange.Find(What:=r, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                   MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not r1 Is Nothing Then
            ws.Name = r
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: can u please tell what you have done here in this line    @SJR                             ==> For Each r In wb2.Sheets(1).Range("B1", wb2.Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Comment: Yes it loops through every cell in column B of your second file. The End(xlup) bit finds the last used cell by working up from the bottom of the sheet. Clear?